# c++ duplicate symbol linker error when sharing a variable in a namespace

Tags: c++, linker, global-variables, extern

Still relatively new to C++

I have a header variable with a namespace with a few constants that looks something like this

```
namespace blah {
    const std::string x="foo";
}
```

I have no problems accessing the variables this way - dosomething(blah::x); etc. Now I want to change the variable so it can be modified. If I just take out the const I get a linker error "duplicate symbol blah::x". Adding an extern here doesn't help:

```
namespace blah {
    extern std::string x;
}
```

It says that extern is enabled by default and I get the same duplicate symbol error. Whats the right way to do this?

(EDIT in the latter case, I don't want to set the variable value yet. I want to derive it elsewhere and share the value. To clarify - I want to get rid of the const so I can change the value (e.g. using command line arguments. When I get rid of the const is when I get the errors about duplicate symbols.)

Answer (score 7):

In the header file, you should *declare* the variable:

```
//blah.h
namespace blah {
   extern std::string x; //declaration
}
```

And in the source file, you should *define* it as:

```
//blah.cpp
#include "blah.h"
namespace blah {
    std::string x="foo"; //definition
}
```

Now include `blah.h` in as many file as you want. You wouldn't see any redefinition error.

If you want to get rid of `const` (as you said in the comment), then simply remove it, as I did.

Comment: @rv6: If you want to get rid of `const`, then simply remove it, as I did.

Answer (score 2):

Declare the `extern` in a header file:

### code.h

```
namespace blah {
  extern std::string x;
};
```

...and *define* it in a single CPP file...

### code.cpp

```
std::string blah::x = "foo";
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a header file that declares your extern:

```
namespace blah {
    extern std::string x;
}
```

Then create a source file that contains the definition:

```
namespace blah {
    std::string x="foo";
}
```

This way the definition gets compiled once in a lib (which you will link with), and won't be defined multiple times (everywhere you include the header).